# grep: matching on literal "+"

Tags: regex, cygwin, grep

I need to find occurrences of "(+)" in my sql scripts, (i.e., Oracle outer join expressions). Realizing that "+", "(", and ")" are all special regex characters, I tried:

```
grep "\(\+\)" *
```

Now this does return occurrences of "(+)", but other lines as well. (Seemingly anything with open and close parens on the same line.) Recalling that parens are only special for extended grep, I tried:

```
grep "(\+)" *
grep "(\\+)" *
```

Both of these returned only lines that contain "()". So assuming that "+" can't be escaped, I tried an old trick:

```
grep "([+])" *
```

That works. I cross-checked the result with a non-regex tool.

**Question**: Can someone explain what exactly is going on with the "+" character? Is there a less kludgy way to match on "(+)"?

(I am using the cygwin grep command.)

**EDIT**: Thanks for the solutions. -- And now I see that, per the GNU grep manual that Bruno referenced, "`\+`" when used in a *basic* expression gives "+" its *extended* meaning, and therefore matches one-or-more "("s followed by a ")". And in my files that's always "()".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

GNU grep (which is included in Cygwin) supports two syntaxes for regular expressions: basic and extended. `grep` uses basic regular expressions and `egrep` or `grep -E` uses extended regular expressions. The basic difference, from the [grep manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/doc/grep_12.html#SEC12), is the following:

> In basic regular expressions the metacharacters `?`, `+`, `{`, `|`, `(`, and `)` lose their special meaning; instead use the backslashed versions `\?`, `\+`, `\{`, `\|`, `\(`, and `\)`.

Since you want the *ordinary* meaning of the characters `(` `+` `)`, either of the following two forms should work for your purpose:

```
grep "(+)" *       # Basic
egrep "\(\+\)" *   # Extended
```

Comment: I just discovered that your second example works, not the first. Hmm. Is cygwin grep busted??

Comment: What is the output of grep --version? For me, it works for "grep (GNU grep) 2.5.1".

Comment: Hmm, same here: grep (GNU grep) 2.5.1

Comment: And the following does not work? echo -e "(+)\n()\n+" | grep "(+)"

Comment: Ah, that is working! (I didn't realize you dropped the \ in front of +) So duh, "+" is also an extended regex. I was stubbornly thinking is was a basic. THANKS.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to add some backslashes because the shell is swallowing them.

ETA: Actually, I just tried on my Cygwin and `grep "(+)"` seems to work just fine for what you want.

Comment: I just tried grep -E "\(\+\)" *, and that works. So it's does not seem to be a shell issue. Could cygwin non-extended regex be broken??

Comment: Too bad only one answer can be accepted. Bruno walked me through it, but you were correct as well. I had forgotten that "+" is also only special for extended regex.

Comment: No, those characters should be fine inside a double-quoted string.