# + not working with grep

Tags: regex, grep

I'm trying to select a certain sequence of nucleotides from a file using `grep`. The sequence should be `AC` followed by 1 or more `A`s.

If I try the following command:

```
grep 'ACA*' nucleotides.txt
```

It works, but this isn't actually what I want. I really need that after `C` there's at least an `A`, so the supposed correct regex should be

```
grep 'ACA+' nucleotides.txt
```

but it doesn't match anything, even if the file clearly contains those patterns.

What's wrong with `grep 'ACA+' nucleotides.txt`?

Comment: Inverse duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/188787/2564301 - still, you should read that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

grep distinguishes between basic and extended regular expressions.  In basic regular expressions, some characters (`+` being among them) have their literal meaning.  The possibility to escape them to obtain their special meaning is an extension of GNU grep (as mentioned by Benjamin W.).

An alternative to

```
grep 'ACA\+'
```

is to use `egrep` (deprecated according to the GNU grep man page), or `grep -E`, such that you can use extended regular expressions, where `+` has the meaning as you expected:

```
grep -E 'ACA+'
```

You find all this (including the list of characters for which this applies) in the grep man page.

So, which approach is better?  As mentioned above the support for `\+` within basic regular expressions may not work with some implementations of grep.  If you aim for portability on POSIX compliant systems, `grep -E` is preferable.

Comment: Why is `egrep` deprecated?

Comment: GNU grep supports `\+` in BRE as an extension; [POSIX BRE](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_03) doesn't have the `+` as a metacharacter.

Comment: @BenjaminW.: Thanks for the hint - I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: So really, for GNU grep, the difference between `grep` and `grep -E` is only what you have to escape and what not. Same with GNU sed and the `-r` flag.

Comment: @nbro `egrep` and `fgrep` are deprecated because you don't need to support 3 separate commands to all do slightly different flavors of the same thing (ie. `g/re/p`), all you need is one command, `grep`, with a couple of options.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape it:

```
grep 'ACA\+' nucleotides.txt
```

Comment: Oh, thanks! How do I know which characters need to be escaped?

Comment: I've also noticed that if I use the option `-E` (for extended), I don't need to escape `+`...

Comment: @nbro - google Basic, Extended, and Perl Compatible Regular Expressions (BREs, EREs, and PCREs) and learn which tools support which with which options (hint: sed = BREs by default, can be extended to EREs; awk = EREs or Strings; grep = BREs by default, can be extended to EREs or Strings and some versions to PCREs).